# Can i change the template of the ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a use case where i want to modify the whole template of the ui-grid. When i searched the files in the GitHub repository, i found that they use a template for the grid but couldn't find a way to change it anywhere. I also posted the same issue there but didn't get any response from them yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to replace any used template with a custom template. In the documentation you can find which gridOptions to use to define your own custom templates. You may choose rowTemplate, cellTemplate, footerTemplate, headerTemplate, etc. It is advisable to use the existing ui-grid template as starting point for creating your own custom template.

If you follow [this example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20317%20Custom%20Templates), you should be able to figure it out, I think :)

Comment: The documentation just tells you how to change the grid row template, cell template, etc. but i wanted to change the whole grid template. There is no details in the documentation on how i can achieve this.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that from your question. Sorry.
In that case you could put all your custom templates in the $templateCache, using the names that ui-grid uses. E.g.  `$templateCache.put('ui-grid/ui-grid-footer', '...your custom template code...');`.
UI-grid will then use your custom templates instead of the default ui-grid templates.